# Where can I find hasura log file

Tags: docker, logging, graphql, hasura

Am running Hasura Graphql engine on docker and I need to make use of the log file that hasura produces.
How can i find the path of the log file in hasura container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose logs container_name`

is what I am using

more is in docs https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/deployment/logging.html